# Bibliography - article not showing title in italics for one of the references

Tags: biblatex

Anyone know why this is not showing up properly?

This is the text...

```
@article{lenstra2012, 
author = "Arjen K. Lenstra1{,} James P. Hughes{,} Maxime Augier{,} Joppe W. Bos{,} Thorsten Kleinjung{,} Christophe Wachter",

title = "Ron was wrong{,} Whit was Right",

year = "2012",
}
```

And the below is how it shows up where the second reference does not have the title in italics (Ron was wrong, Whit was Right)...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome! A complete example would make it easier to help. Without knowing more, it is hard to say. However, article titles are not typeset in italics in any bibliography style I have ever seen. Either they go in quotation marks of some kind. Or they are typeset with just title capitalisation or they are typeset sentence-style. Italics is for journal and book titles etc. - not the articles.

Comment: But you should use `and` to separate authors in the author list. And why are all your commas in curly brackets? If `Whit` is a proper name, you want `{Whit} was Right`, for example.

Comment: @cfr - Oh I didn't know.   Sorry today is the first day I use LaTex as our professor wants us to use it for our Outline / Final paper so just getting the hang of it.

Comment: @cfr - Also, I thought I needed to use brackets around the commas.  I found another post on here that mentioned that's how it should be handled.  I'll switch to and which I would prefer anyway.  Whit should proper yeah.  Why in full brackets though?  The first letter not enough?  I noticed that afterwards as well

Comment: You are really better off using `{}` to enclose each field rather than `""` (though, technically, both are allowed).  @cfr -- Some (many?) journals in (Anglo-American) law use italics for journal article titles, while putting journal names and book titles in "titlecase" small caps. (Utterly horrendous, but given the common law fondness for "precedent", it is hard to see them changing any time soon....) And don't get me started on the way these journals "order" the elements of a citation!

Comment: @jon Ych! I didn't know that. If this is for work in law, though, I suspect the `.bib` file will need to be rather more meticulously constructed than this fragment suggests ;).

Comment: If you want to change the title into italics you would need to tell us what bibliography package you use. You have tagged this question `biblatex`, is that accurate, or do you use `natbib` or `cite`? We would also need to know the style you use (either `.bst` or `biblatex` style). So please consider adding a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) so we can see how you arrived at the output you got.

Comment: Is there any update here? I'm not eve really sure what you ask about and aside from the obvious problems with your code that have already been pointed out, there is nothing more for us to get out of the code and image you have posted.

Comment: Hey sorry.  I'm good with leaving it as is.  I guess just assumed that the title would be italicized.  Since you guys said it's not common to see that for a journal article, I just accepted that fact and left it as is

Comment: I have voted this question as "unclear what you are asking", as I find the question quite unclear in what it actually is about and because the OP is OK with what they get currently ...

Comment: I got my answer but I went ahead and updated the post so it was a bit more clear on what I was asking